# Le « bon viveur » existe-t-il en français et diffère-t-il du « bon vivant » ?

Tags: sens, anglais

La section britannique du *Collins* (aussi [*Cambridge*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bon-vivant)) contient une entrée particulière pour « [bon vivant](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bon-vivant) »:

> [...]a person who enjoys luxuries, esp good food and drink *Also
> called (but not in French):* **bon viveur**[...]
>
> [ *Collins online* ]

En français, on connaît le « *bon [vivant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vivant)* » (aussi [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/vivant)):

> − Subst. masc. Bon vivant. Personne d'humeur joviale qui apprécie les
> plaisirs de la vie. *La mort n'est pas loin. Capitaine, J'aime la vie,
> et vivre est la chose certaine, Mais rien ne sait mourir comme les
> bons vivants. Moi, je donne mon cœur, mais ma peau, je la vends* (Hugo,
> *Légende*, t. 5, 1877, p. 977). *Il faut bien rire un peu, dit-il au
> factionnaire et le factionnaire le regarde passer avec ce regard figé
> qu'ont parfois les bons vivants devant les mauvais* (Prévert, *Paroles*,
> 1946, p. 18).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* - TLFi ]

On note au *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (A. Rey, ed. Le Robert) que ça remonte à 1680 et qu'on avait « *vivant* » dans le même sens (1698) mais que c'est sorti d'usage aujourd'hui. M. Rey ne semble pas en parler dans l'ouvrage qu'il dirige, mais le [*viveur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/viveur) existe (identifié comme néologisme au vieux [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/viveur)):

> *Vieilli*. Homme qui mène une vie de plaisir, une existence dissipée. Synon. *débauché, fêtard, noceur. Tholomyès était un viveur de trente
> ans, mal conservé. Il était ridé et édenté; et il ébauchait une
> calvitie dont il disait lui-même sans tristesse: crâne à trente ans,
> genou à quarante* (Hugo, *Misér.*, t. 1, 1862, p. 157). *Une société de
> débauche, quelques bêtes de plaisir (...), des viveurs, des
> politiciens, des êtres inutiles, toute cette agitation qui passe, sans
> la toucher, au-dessus de la nation* (Rolland, J.-Chr., Maison, 1909,
> p. 945). 
> − *Au fém., rare. Je donne rendez-vous à une barrière; là mon
> galant monte, on abat les volets et en route pour Cythère. (...) je
> suis une viveuse, le féminin de viveur, voilà tout; (...) dois-je me
> priver d'amants quand ces messieurs ont des maîtresses (...)?*
> (Péladan, *Vice supr.*, 1884, p. 71).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* - TLFi ]

Aucune référence au « bon viveur » comme tel ici. Cependant on [retrouve](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=viveur%2Cbon%20viveur%2Cbon%20vivant&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cviveur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbon%20viveur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbon%20vivant%3B%2Cc0) quand même en français une (faible) fréquence de cet emploi, dont certains qui semblent anciens.

---

Le « bon viveur » existe-t-il bien en français ? Est-ce un régionalisme ? Diffère-t-il du « bon vivant » à quelques qu'égards; est-ce une version améliorée du *viveur* ?

Comment: "[Being a] bon viveur - in fact, 'tis his métier."  Sure beats that of heretic-burning, imo! (Does all this borrowing from French mean that English could have used its own version of Bill 101? Regardless, Mark Twain and I are glad there wasn't one 'cause we'd all be speaking [something closer to] German if not for the wonderful French [influence]!)

Comment: @PapaPoule But then again, looking at Hugo's description of viveur Tholomyès, one wonders where the hardship falls loll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il semblerait, outre que l'expression soit sans doute inconnue en français, que le terme de *viveur* lui-même ait une connotation péjorative ou à tout le moins un peu morbide à l'opposé du traditionnel *bon vivant* (Dict. Acad., 8<sup>e</sup> éd.)

> n. m. Celui qui abuse de la vie.

[Le DVLF de l'université de Chicago](http://dvlf.uchicago.edu/mot/viveur) donne un emploi moins rare du terme autour de 1880.

Comment: Merci! Oui, déjà dans la définition du viveur on parle du "débauché" comme synonyme, alors il y a une connotation négative qui diffère de ce qu'on retrouve avec le bon vivant. Il faut souligner que dans le petit graphe sur _DVLF_, on illustre la fréquence de _viveur_ et ça correspond au ngram que j'ai présenté. Est-ce que la réponse signifie que le "bon viveur" n'existerait pas et que seul le viveur existe?

Comment: *Bon viveur* est une locution britannique; je ne l'ai jamais rencontrée en français. À quel moment a-t-elle quitté le français pour l'anglais, ça…

Comment: Moi non plus je n'avais jamais rencontré, sauf que [c'est là](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22bon%20viveur%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr), et ça se retrouve dans un livre par exemple [celui-ci](http://books.google.com/books?id=WdjUP8jvDL4C&lpg=PA62&dq="bon+viveur"&pg=PA62&) en 2005. C'est un calque?

Comment: Peut-être s'agit-il *à la fois* d'un archaïsme *et* d'un emprunt (un calque, je ne pense pas qu'on puisse dire cela: ça reste du français contemporain, tant sur le plan du lexique que de la syntaxe), selon où les auteurs contemporains qui l'utilisent l'ont entendu ou lu (détour ou non par l'anglais); en tout cas, il semblerait étonnant que cette expression ne soit pas française à l'origine et il ne tient qu'à vous de l'utiliser pour qu'elle le redevienne, si tant est que son usage actuel ne soit quasiment plus qu'un “calque” pour le moment.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'avais jamais entendu cette expression.
Je parle de *bon viveur*, pas de *bon vivant*.

Et après avoir regardé le lien donné ici pointant vers un article en anglais de Wikipédia, sur l'expression "bon viveur" en anglais, l'article disant:

> The phrase bon viveur is a **pseudo-French** phrase adopted in English in the mid 19th century, **modelled on** the French bon vivant "

J'étais sûre qu'il s'agissait, comme le mot "pseudo-français" l'indique, d'une tentative ratée d'emprunt au français d'une expression, se trouvant déformée en anglais. Comme par exemple "double-entendre" pour dire "double sens".

Le *pseudo-latin*, par exemple, et se produit quand des gens qui n'ont pas de connaissance du latin, essayent d'emprunter une expression latine, et intervertissent -us et -um, par exemple. Cela se produit souvent.

Si des anglophones, qui n'ont jamais appris le français, essayent de réutiliser une expression française, ils la déforment. J'ai vu souvent des *omelettes du fromage*, par exemple. Et quand il existe un mot proche (vivant/viveur) ou une irrégularité, la déformation est encore plus susceptible de se produire.

Mais ce que dit l'article de Wikipédia n'est pas exact.
Les anglais n'ont rien "modelé sur le modèle de..." du tout.
Et surtout pas sur "bon vivant" qui est apparu plus tard.

Bien que tout le monde l'ait oubliée, cette expression a existé en français.
Et c'est plutôt l'anglais qui a gardé cette vieille expression figée, et elle continué d'évoluer en français...

On trouve dans la littérature:

> ***Bon viveur*** "jeune qui sait le mieux jouir de la vie, soit lorsqu'il est heureux, au milieu des adversités"

Dictionnaire de l'Académie Française (1836)

Et en cherchant, on le trouve dans divers textes du XIXème siècle (ça semble dater de cette époque).
Par exemple:

> Un ministre protestant est un bon viveur, qui va trinquer à la guinguette avec ses paroissiens.

ça semble être exactement l'emploi du moderne *bon vivant*.
Peut-être un côté davantage péjoratif dans certains textes pour "bon viveur"?
Je ne sais pas, c'est à vérifier.

Et pourquoi viveur est devenu vivant, c'est un mystère.
Peut-être l'erreur d'un écrivain, ou la confusion avec une autre expression;

Viveur est en effet plus logique que "vivant", qui a déjà le sens d*'être en vie*.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a "mot à mot" translation from English but it exists as an expression, explained also in wikipedia ;

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bon_viveur

but I am pretty sure that it is not used so much in conversations.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by a word for word translation from English. Those are French words. Also viveur exists in French, but "bon viveur" is instantiated very lightly in the Books corpus in Fr. yet nobody talks about his expression in French. The English side of this is mostly off topic but it seems this is only used in the UK. I speculate "bon vivant" sounded feminine in English when it crossed over to England; purely speculative. But does it exist in French? Could you maybe expand on what your take is of the article you link to and its bearing. Thanks!

Comment: @user3177 The answer is not very well worded, it's not a word for word translation from English, it's "pseudo-French" That means they try to borrow a French expression, but turn it into something else, because of mistakes and confusion between several French words. (it's what the article says, but I'm not sure they're right)